# IE11 renders website in IE5 settings

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11

I recently made up a HTML/CSS/JS(query) site that looks fine in any browser, any device.

But on ONE device (desktop PC) of one colleague it just renders nonsense. There is only one element visible, totally wrong color and text-style.

When I open the **Developer Tools (F12)** and go to the tab *Emulation*, it shows me that *Internet Explorer 5* is the default emulation engine. When I change this to *Edge* or *Internet Explorer 11* - BOOM! perfect website rendering.

As I deactivated all browser add-ons and resetted it to default settings, I guess that anywhere it is stated that this browser should use *Internet Explorer 5* as the default engine.

Where can I change the default emulation engine?

This error also happens on several other sites on this website. Is there a way to prevent it?

Comment: Did you specify the doctype as `<!DOCTYPE html>`. If yes, it should by default render your page in edge mode.

Comment: Also, uncheck _Display intranet sites in Compatibility View_ from **Compatibility View Settings** in tools dropdown menu.

Comment: @VibhorDube Yes, when I add this line, it switches to *Internet Explorer 9* view, which doesn't render the site good, as well. You can see more, but... meh. Your second comment should be written as an answer, though. It has cured this IE from doing insane things. Works!

Comment: Okay then, posting it as an answer. Happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While on an intranet network, please make sure that following option is unchecked.

Press 'Alt+T' to open tools menu and select **Compatibility View settings**, uncheck *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View*.

Comment: You may add `<!DOCTYPE html>` for universal application. I guess this one didn't work for me in the first place, as *Display intranet sites in Compatibility View* was active and has overwritten this setting. This answer has worked, thanks for that!